# increasing batch size during inference

Tags: pytorch, gpu

I believed that the inference time per batch was independent of the batch size when using a GPU, but this minimal example tells me that this doesn't seem true:

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from tqdm import tqdm

BATCH_SIZE = 32
N_ITER = 10000

class NN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NN, self).__init__()
        self.layer = nn.Conv2d(3, 32, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=3, bias=False)

    def forward(self, input):
        out = self.layer(input)
        return out
    
cnn = NN().cuda()
cnn.eval()
tensor = torch.rand(BATCH_SIZE, 3, 999, 999).cuda()
with torch.no_grad():
    for _ in tqdm(range(N_ITER), mininterval=0.1):
        out = cnn(tensor)
```

When increasing BATCH_SIZE, the "it/s" shown by tqdm increases proportionally:

[Plot of inference time vs batch size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5jFa.png)

It was my believe that the GPU can process the entire tensor simultaneously, as long as it doesn't use all the memory. Maybe I don't understand something about how GPUs process data in parallel, so I would appreciate some insights here.

I am using a NVIDIA GeForce 2080 Ti, pytorch 1.6.0 and CUDA 10.2.

Answer (score -1):

You are wrong. GPUs have a lot of cores but that does not mean that they can process *all* the data at the same time. For instance, RTX 2080Ti only has 4352 cores.